# Fourier Optics - Distribution on Fourier Plane

Tags: optics, fourier-transform

Suppose we have a lens of focal length $f$. The general statement of Fourier Optics goes as follows:

Given an aperture function f(x, y) in the **front focal plane**, the lens "effectively" takes the fourier transform of this function, producing a distribtuion of $\vec{k}$ vectors $F(k_x, k_y)$ once the light has been shone through the lens.

My question is as follows. Suppose we put a piece of cardboard on the **back focal plane.**

[image]

How does $g(x, y)$ (the distribution of light on the back fourier plane) relate to $F(k_x, k_y)$. Feel free to answer in terms of $\lambda$ (the wavelength of light) and $f$ (the focal length of the lens).

To be absolutely clear, I'm essentially look at how $(k_x, k_y)$ maps to $(x, y)$ on the **back focal plane.** The image $g(x_2, y_2)$ will appear as the fourier transform of $f(x_1, y_1)$ with $x_2$ and $y_2$ being a scalar factor times $k_x$ and $k_y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mapping from the angular spectrum $F(\mathbf{k})$ to the output amplitude distribution $g(\mathbf{x})$ of a 2f system (where $\mathbf{k}=\{k_x,k_y\}$ and $\mathbf{x}=\{x,y\}$) simply follows from the relationship between there coordinates:
$$ \mathbf{k} = \frac{\mathbf{x}}{\lambda f} . $$
One can see this directly from the expression of the output after a 2f system. It is a Fourier transform, but the frequency domain coordinates are represented in this way in terms of the position coordinates in the output plane.

Comment: See that's what I suspected; but I'm actually measuring this stuff in a lab with a $200$mm lens and a $685$nm laser. This implies that the spacing on the wall $\vec{x} = \lambda f \vec{k}$ is extremely small (compared to the fourier transform function). Much much smaller than what I'm actually measuring

Comment: Is the wall one focal length behind the lens?

Comment: The small prediction that I initially doubted is indeed correct. I am currently running simulations on calculated vs measured fourier transforms from an image in the lab and they correspond perfectly using your formula.